# Readonly fields in Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions

I am trying to implement the read only field in Tridion 2013 SP1 using GUI Extension. I have followed all the steps provided [in this article](http://yabolka.com/gui-extension-readonly-and-hidden-fields-in-tridion-2011-and-up/)

But it is not working. Hope I have missed something at the last step -

Here is the entry for for my extension in `System.config` file  -

```
<editor name="Readonly">
       <installpath>D:\tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Editors\Readonly</installpath>
       <configuration>Readonly.config</configuration>
       <vdir>Readonly</vdir>
</editor>
```

May I have to add any thing else into the System.config ? Please suggest.

Comment: you need to check with the creator if that actually works, you can also checkout the [Field Behavior Injection extension](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/fbi) that was created a couple of years back, It never was completely finished, but we did have stuff like readonly working if I remember correctly.

Comment: Please open the JavaScript console and see what errors are showing up.  Most likely something in the .js of the extension is not working.  When I wrote the article it did work on my Tridion 2011 system, but I noticed that some 2011 extensions need a small update in the JS file to work with 2013.  However, I forgot what that small adjustment was....

Answer (score 3):

Did you try it with the comment from Mark Sizer at the bottom of the article?

Also - this would be needed for Production systems.  For Dev, I usually disable the GUI minification feature, to make debugging extensions easier...

```
var addJquery = function ()
{
// … jQuery here …
//YM: to avoid conflict with the Outbound Email extension, we define a new shorthand for jQuery
window.$j = jQuery.noConflict(true);
};
addJquery();
```

Comment: As it is the POC server, I have disabled the GUI minification feature

Answer (score 2):

Did you update the `modification` number in the system.config file?

When you say

> not working

what do you mean?

[ ] Crashes your computer,

[ ] Tridion doesn't load > nothing,

[ ] Tridion doesn't load > partially renders,

[ ] gives a JS error in the JS Console,

[ ] Writes something specific to the logs.

The more information you can provide with regards what you have looked at / confirmed will help us help you.